# how to use lldb trace-thread and python SBThread eBroadcastBitSelectedFrameChanged event

Tags: python, debugging, lldb

I want to trace thread by log all the symbol it call, so I found tow method

1、the lldb settings list:

'target.process.thread' variables:
  trace-thread           -- If true, this thread will single-step and log execution.

it means the lldb will log execution, but I can't find where is the log

2、lldb python SBThread has a event eBroadcastBitSelectedFrameChanged, I think it will callback when thread frame change, but why SBThread has no broadcaster?

Answer (score 0):

1) This setting was put in mostly to help diagnose problems with lldb's stepping algorithms.  Since it causes all execution to go by instruction single step, it's going to make your program execute very slowly, so it hasn't been used for anything other than that purpose (and I haven't used it for that purpose in a good while, so it might have bit-rotted.)  The output is supposed to go to the debugger's stdout.

2) `eBroadcastBitSelectedFrameChanged` is only sent when the user changes the selected frame with command line commands.  It's meant to allow a GUI like Xcode that also allows command line interaction to keep the GUI sync'ed with user commands in the console.  There isn't a GetBroadcaster for threads, because threads come and go and you generally want to listen to ALL the threads, not just a particular one.  To do that, call `SBThread.GetBroadcasterClassName` and then sign your listener up for events by class name (`StartListeningForEventClass`).

If you have a need to listen to a particular thread, file an enhancement request to the bug tracker at http://lldb.llvm.org.

Comment: is there any method that I can use lldb to collect arm level instructions execution? such as which instructions executed or which symbol called

Comment: Short of instruction-single stepping, lldb doesn't offer much for this sort of investigation.  And besides being very slow, you're also going to have to catch and stop all new threads so you can single-step them as well.  Depending on what you are trying to do a coverage tool like llvm-cov or something in Instruments might be a better bet.